# RDS SQL server TLS/SSL encrytion from application servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, tls1.2, aws-acm

Need to encrypt data in transit from application severs to RDS SQL server with SSL/TLS?

I see aws gives the option to make `force encryption = true` in parameter group with self signed certs.

Is there a way to use customer certs to import into RDS?

Any configuration steps to do this at application server and on RDS?

Appreciate any info on this . Didn't find anything in AWS knowledge base.
Note: Application servers sit behind load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RDS SQL Server you will need to use the PEM that AWS provides for TLS.

You have a [choice of either](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html):

- [Root certificate](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem)
- [Intermediary and root certificate](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)

The application server will need to have access to this certificate before it can connect to the RDS instance.

Unfortunately at this time only Aurora supports uploading your own certificates (and then accessing via ACM), you will need to use the provided one.

For connecting and configuring the RDS there is a specific [Using SSL with a Microsoft SQL Server DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.SSL.Using.html) page.

Comment: I will try this. Appreciate your response @Chris. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any additional pointers :)

Comment: ..i have enabled force_ssl param =true in parameter group. I think  this uses root ca by default.  Like to know what version of TLS is this ? i am looking TLS 1.2 version. There is no version mentioned in AWS document . Also, what is this parameter  CACertificateIdentifier in RDS resource creation. Is it required if we have force_ssl in parameter group ?

Comment: Having `force_ssl` will reject any connections over plain text, regarding TLS version I too cannot see anywhere the versions supported there are values in parameter group of `rds.tls10`, `rds.tls11` and `rds.tls12`. They support a value of `default, enabled, disabled`

Comment: Yeah. Regarding versions will check with AWS. Cheers!